# How to execute a index match type process to copy a value and fill a column (Appended Queries)

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a table Query that has another Query appended which it giving me the qty of certain material. I want to take that qty from the appended query and copy it up the remaining column cells for that specific material #. As of now every cell in the column is null with the exception of the cells from the appended query.
I guess you can relate this to a index match type process, I need to index the qty on hand and match it to the material # from the appended query.
See images below.

Qty on hand column is null
[image: Qty on hand is null]

Appended query at the bottom starting at row 1067, need to take qty on hand values and copy those values to call remaining cells in the column that are linked to that part #.
[image: Need to take qty on hand from appended query and copy those values up for those specific material to the rest of the column.]

Comment: Why would you do this? Don't append the second Query, merge it with the first query matching on Part#, and expand the matched colum to show Quantity on Hand

Comment: It wouldn't let me merge queries, that was my first approach. When i select the consignment inventory query to merge; the bottom of the screen drop down where you select "Join Kind"; every option given does not alloy me to click the "OK" button at the bottom.

Comment: you need to post a copy of the file somewhere for us to look at